# fade out an element at end of page

Tags: jquery

Hey I´m having a hard time trying to fade out an element when it reaches the end of the page... I know hot to fade it out at the top of the page, but i can figure it out, this is the one that I have so far

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){ 
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) { 
            $('#scroll').fadeIn(500);
            $('.scroll2').fadeIn(500);
        } else { 
            $('#scroll').fadeOut(500); 
            $('.scroll2').fadeOut(500); 
        }    
    });
```

I just tried with this but still not working

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
           $('.scroll2').fadeOut(500);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear to me. Are you asking for a solution to A) know when a particular element touches the bottom of the window or B) know when the document was scrolled all the way to the bottom? @rion gave you an answer to B). if you need A) you may want to look at [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/). E.g.: (pseudo code from head) `offset.top of element + element height + window.scrolltop >= document.height`

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if you have reached the bottom of the document by comparing the sum of the current position `$(window).scrollTop()` and the height of the window `$(window).height()` to see if it is equal to the overall height of the entire page `$(document).height()`:

```
// If you have scrolled to the bottom of the document...
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
    // Fade out stuff here
}
```

**Example**

[image]

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    // If you have scrolled to the bottom of the document...
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
      $("#example").fadeOut();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1500px;
}
#example {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #0071bc;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>

<div id='example'>
  This should fade out at the bottom
</div>
```

Comment: hey I just edited the question with that code but still not working

Comment: The code should be correct. I've added an example snippet demonstrating it. You may want to check to see if you have any jQuery-related errors within the Developer Tools (F12) in your browser.